# Caused by: io.cucumber.datatable.UndefinedDataTableTypeException: Can't convert DataTable to List

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am updating cucumber version from 3x to 7x and I faced following exception:

```
Caused by: io.cucumber.datatable.UndefinedDataTableTypeException: Can't convert DataTable to List

There was no table entry or table row transformer registered for com.x.config
   Please consider registering a table entry or row transformer.
```

and code is as follows:

```
    @And("^configurations$")
    public void configurations(List<Config> configs) {
        initialConfigs = configs.stream().map(cfg -> Config.builder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve it, by adding `Transformer` in step definition that should be as follows:

```
 @DataTableType
    public Config entryTransformer(Map<String, String> row) {

        return Config.builder()
                .id(Integer.parseInt(row.get("id")))
                .active(row.get("active"))
                .build();
    }
```